# .css is not geting called from the View (Asp.net MVC4)

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following code for a pop-up. Right now the pop is coming but clicking on the close button the window is not closing.

```
<div id="@String.Concat("PopUp", @Model.UserID)" class="reveal-modal">
 @Html.Label("Enter valid mobile number")
 @Html.TextBoxFor(user => user.Mobile)           

<input id="proceed" type="submit" value="Proceed" />    
<input id="reenter" type="submit" value="Re-Enter" />    
<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
```

And the jQuery is as follows. While running the file, the close button is not calling any css methods

```
(function ($) {

/*---------------------------
 Defaults for Reveal
----------------------------*/

/*---------------------------
 Listener for data-reveal-id attributes
----------------------------*/

$('a[data-reveal-id]').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();        
    var modalLocation = $(this).attr('data-reveal-id');
    $('#' + modalLocation).reveal($(this).data());
});

/*---------------------------
 Extend and Execute
----------------------------*/

$.fn.reveal = function (options) {


    var defaults = {
        animation: 'fadeAndPop', //fade, fadeAndPop, none
        animationspeed: 300, //how fast animtions are
        closeonbackgroundclick: true, //if you click background will modal close?
        dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal' //the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
    };

    //Extend dem' options
    var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    return this.each(function () {

        /*---------------------------
         Global Variables
        ----------------------------*/
        var modal = $(this),
            topMeasure = parseInt(modal.css('top')),
            topOffset = modal.height() + topMeasure,
            locked = false,
            modalBG = $('.reveal-modal-bg');

        /*---------------------------
         Create Modal BG
        ----------------------------*/
        if (modalBG.length == 0) {
            modalBG = $('<div class="reveal-modal-bg" />').insertAfter(modal);
        }

        /*---------------------------
         Open & Close Animations
        ----------------------------*/
        //Entrance Animations
        modal.bind('reveal:open', function () {
            modalBG.unbind('click.modalEvent');
            $('.' + options.dismissmodalclass).unbind('click.modalEvent');
            if (!locked) {
                lockModal();
                if (options.animation == "fadeAndPop") {
                    modal.css({ 'top': $(document).scrollTop() - topOffset, 'opacity': 0, 'visibility': 'visible' });
                    modalBG.fadeIn(options.animationspeed / 2);
                    modal.delay(options.animationspeed / 2).animate({
                        "top": $(document).scrollTop() + topMeasure + 'px',
                        "opacity": 1
                    }, options.animationspeed, unlockModal());
                }
                if (options.animation == "fade") {
                    modal.css({ 'opacity': 0, 'visibility': 'visible', 'top': $(document).scrollTop() + topMeasure });
                    modalBG.fadeIn(options.animationspeed / 2);
                    modal.delay(options.animationspeed / 2).animate({
                        "opacity": 1
                    }, options.animationspeed, unlockModal());
                }
                if (options.animation == "none") {
                    modal.css({ 'visibility': 'visible', 'top': $(document).scrollTop() + topMeasure });
                    modalBG.css({ "display": "block" });
                    unlockModal()
                }
            }
            modal.unbind('reveal:open');
        });

        //Closing Animation
        modal.bind('reveal:close', function () {
            if (!locked) {
                lockModal();
                if (options.animation == "fadeAndPop") {
                    modalBG.delay(options.animationspeed).fadeOut(options.animationspeed);
                    modal.animate({
                        "top": $(document).scrollTop() - topOffset + 'px',
                        "opacity": 0
                    }, options.animationspeed / 2, function () {
                        modal.css({ 'top': topMeasure, 'opacity': 1, 'visibility': 'hidden' });
                        unlockModal();
                    });
                }
                if (options.animation == "fade") {
                    modalBG.delay(options.animationspeed).fadeOut(options.animationspeed);
                    modal.animate({
                        "opacity": 0
                    }, options.animationspeed, function () {
                        modal.css({ 'opacity': 1, 'visibility': 'hidden', 'top': topMeasure });
                        unlockModal();
                    });
                }
                if (options.animation == "none") {
                    modal.css({ 'visibility': 'hidden', 'top': topMeasure });
                    modalBG.css({ 'display': 'none' });
                }
            }
            modal.unbind('reveal:close');
        });

        /*---------------------------
         Open and add Closing Listeners
        ----------------------------*/
        //Open Modal Immediately
        modal.trigger('reveal:open')

        //Close Modal Listeners
        var closeButton = $('.' + options.dismissmodalclass).bind('click.modalEvent', function () {
            modal.trigger('reveal:close')
        });

        if (options.closeonbackgroundclick) {
            modalBG.css({ "cursor": "pointer" })
            modalBG.bind('click.modalEvent', function () {
                modal.trigger('reveal:close')
            });
        }
        $('body').keyup(function (e) {
            if (e.which === 27) { modal.trigger('reveal:close'); } // 27 is the keycode for the Escape key
        });


        /*---------------------------
         Animations Locks
        ----------------------------*/
        function unlockModal() {
            locked = false;
        }
        function lockModal() {
            locked = true;
        }

    });//each call
}//orbit plugin call
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: What version of jQuery do you use? `live` was deprecated in 1.7 and was removed in 1.9. Read [live()](https://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: @MuraliMurugesan its 1.7. The same code and file i have used for some other MVC4 projects which is working and this is not!